# Incorrect message using SMS AT commands

Tags: vb.net, winforms, sms, at-command

I currently have the code below where it is working normally in the first time I clicked where txtmessage = hi. However when firing the button for the second time the message I received is now different where AT commands are included in the message. Any thoughts on this?

```
Private Sub cmdsend_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdsend.Click
    Try
        With SerialPort1
            .Write("at" & vbCrLf)
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
            .Write("at+cmgf=1" & vbCrLf)
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
            .Write("at+cmgs=" & Chr(34) & txtnumber.Text & Chr(34) & vbCrLf)
            .Write(txtmessage.Text & Chr(26))
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
            MsgBox(rcvdata.ToString)
        End With

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Here is the sample message I received.

```
at

at+cmgf=1

at+cmgs="09301290xxx"

hi
```

Comment: Given that the `SerialPort` class has a `WriteLine` method, why call `Write` and explicitly tack a line break onto the end of the text?

Comment: Don't use `Chr(34)`. Either use `ControlChars.Quote` or a literal double quote. You should also use string interpolation to aid readability. `.Write("at+cmgs=" & Chr(34) & txtnumber.Text & Chr(34) & vbCrLf)` would be better written `.WriteLine($"at+cmgs=""{txtnumber.Text}""")`.

Comment: Is the `SUB` character after the message supposed to indicate the end of the message? It seems like anything after that is still being interpreted as part of the message so you probably ought to investigate whether you're actually terminating the message correctly. I don't know anything about this topic so I can't tell you but that's what I'd be looking into.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I tried converting to WriteLine but the problem still persist in the sms message. As for the SUB character, yes it should indicate as the end of the message but I don't know why it still continue. I have also try "SMSPort.DiscardInBuffer()" and "SMSPort.DiscardOutBuffer()" Properties after opening and before closing my serial port but it doesn't resolve the issue. The expected message should only be "hi".

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34360/vb-net-AT-commands-to-send-SMS

Comment: In the future I suggest to not post private numbers. Add some `xxxx` to hide some digits. Two thoughts: 1) the AT command terminator is `\r`, not `\r\n`, so just end your commands with `vbCr`. 2) I'm interested in what you see when you print `MsgBox(rcvdata.ToString)`. Then insert this line after each AT command, and come back to us with the output (both successful attempt and the failed one).